# Why is WebSocket(URL) undefined only when hosted and using IE11?

Tags: javascript, websocket, iis-7.5, internet-explorer-11

I have a very simple webpage that is empty except for the following script in the body:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var host = "ws://sample-host/echo";
            var ws = new WebSocket(host);
        </script>
```

I have this page hosted on a web server running IIS 7.5, as part of a classic ASP.NET application.  When I open the page with Chrome or Firefox, the WebSocket constructor function will be called.  When I open the page with IE11, the function is undefined.

I can save the page locally and open it in IE, Chrome, and Firefox, and the constructor is called correctly.

Why is websocket() undefined only when hosted and using IE11?

Comment: is `ws://sample-host/echo` a valid URL? i don't see a TLD

Comment: It is not, however when I use a valid URL the results are the same- IE thinks the function is undefined.  All other browsers will attempt a connection and return a not found error when using an invalid URL.

Comment: could be an edge meta tag rolling IE back. can you post the exact error messages your'e getting?

Comment: @dandavis You are correct, it looks like someone added a custom meta tag in the site's web.config rolling it back to IE9.

Answer (score 0):

By default pages that fall into the "Local Intranet" zone will run IE11 in compatibility mode, usually for IE5, which doesn't support the `WebSocket` constructor.

To override this, there are a few options, one is mentioned in the comments above:

> "You are correct, it looks like someone added a custom meta tag in the site's `web.config` rolling it back to IE9."

... to set this through IIS, modify the `web.config`:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <clear />
      <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

... another option is to force this through an HTML `<meta>` tag...

```html
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   </head>
```

In addition, you may be able to circumvent this problem by defining what "Local Intranet" is...

- IE11, Compatibility View Settings, (Uncheck) **Display Intranet Sites in Compatibility View**

  -- OR --
- IE11, Internet Options, Security, Local Intranet, Sites, (Several Options for defining how to **Detect Intranet Network**)

**Words of caution**...

- Due to the historical nature of this, many environments will break when these settings are tampered with as websites were written with IE5 compatibility in mind.  For these reasons, a page-by-page or site-by-site solution is often preferred over changing settings on the PC.
- Due to the common pairing of Group Policy Domains and IE11 support, "Internet Options" like "Trusted Sites" and "Local Intranet Zone" may be grayed out.  Work with your domain administrator to adjust as needed.